# Conditional using strpos and URLs in PHP

Tags: php, strpos, global

I have the following PHP code to run a conditional block of code. I need a popup to NOT load if the page URL has "/checkout/order-received/" in it.

Here is my current non-working code...

(code in functions file to get current page URL)

```
// Get the page URL to disable the checkout popup.
$GLOBALS['checkout_page_url']  = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

(code in relevant include file)

```
<?php
if (strpos($GLOBALS['checkout_page_url'], '/checkout/order-received/') !== true) {
// show popup
} else {
// do not show popup
}
?>
```

I need the popup to NOT load regardless of the URL if the first part is "/checkout/order-received/"

I know the variable is getting set in the functions file because I'm echoing that out in the footer for testing purposes, so something is wrong with my conditional code.

Comment: `strpos` returns the position or `false` if the needle wasn't found.

Comment: Sometimes looking into the php manual wouldn't be so bad, just saying. http://php.net/strpos

Comment: I guess that means no Boob Squeeze of Gratitude for me Charlotte.  I'll try to be smarter next time.

Comment: Is there even something to squeeze? I don't need to know the answer.

Comment: priceless chat. made my day. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`strpos()` doesn't ever return boolean `true` so it will always NOT EQUAL with the `!==` operator.  It returns an integer character position or boolean `false`:

```
if (strpos($GLOBALS['checkout_page_url'], '/checkout/order-received/') === false) {
```

You must use `===` because it could also return 0 which is `==` to `false`, but means that it was found at position 0.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Versus doing what you corrected, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Probably about how I would do it.